# Gerrit Jenkins trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

According to this site:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger
and section Trigger Configuration with subsection Comment Added i'm a little confused, because seems like trigger after added comment doesn't work. I've trried to add in configuration as comment strings and ints but without any result - recheck didn't trigger. Has anyone idea how to configure it properly to have situation when i add particular comment in gerrit i recive recheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is as following:

You need to add

> Comment Added Contains Regular Expression

Now it works fine.